# mutating global objects in a function in R/passing objects by reference

Tags: r

I have a few dataframes in R, e.g:

```
df1
df2
df3
```

and I'd like to cinduct a few action on them, e.g clear NA values from them:

```
df1[is.na(df1)]=0
df2[is.na(df2)]=0
df3[is.na(df3)]=0
```

I though I could do something like this:

```
lapply(c(df1,df2,df3),function(x){x[is.na(x)]=0})
```

but it doesn't seem to work... I've tried using `<<-` as well.

Am I missing something? How can I change a global object inside a function?

Comment: @akrun's advice is sound, but if possible, I would recommend you put your data.frames in a list. You can use `lapply` ad libidum (to create new modified objects).

Comment: Generally: *don’t* do this. It’s not how R works. Do not modify objects whose scope is outside your function, return the modified objects instead. akrun’s answer works but fixing the root cause rather than circumventing the problem will result in better code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `list2env` to make the changes done with the `lapply` to reflect in the global environment (though not recommended as we can do all the operations in the `list`).

```
list2env(lapply(mget(paste0('df', 1:3)), function(x) 
      replace(x, is.na(x), 0)), envir=.GlobalEnv)
df1
#  col1 col2
#1    0    1
#2    1    2
#3    2    0
#4    3    4
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(col1= c(NA, 1:3), col2= c(1:2, NA, 4))
df2 <- data.frame(col1= c(1:3, NA), col2= c(1, NA, 3, 4))
df3 <- data.frame(col1= c(2,4, NA), col2 = c(1, NA, 2))
```

Comment: @user1762870  sorry forgot to add `function(x)`

Comment: it doesnt work... dataframes still have NA's in them @akrun

Comment: @user1762870  You haven't provided any reproducible example.  But, based on the reproducible example (updated now), it is working.

Comment: @user1762870  Is it possible that the `NA`s in your dataset are character `"NA"`?

Comment: Thanks! Got it, I was having trouble with converting this `mget(paste0('df', 1:3))` to my names